# Symfony/Console: How to use multiple progress bars?

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle, symfony-console

I have a command for Symfony/Console which downloads several files at once using [Guzzle Pool](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=pool#concurrent-requests). I already have Guzzle reporting the [download progress](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#progress) for each file, that works fine.

Now I'd like to improve it using the [ProgressBar helper](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html) from Symfony/Console.The problem is that all examples I found for the ProgressBar only use a single progress bar. I need several independent progress bars - one for each of the downloads. Can you give me some hint how to achieve that?

Comment: FYI when using console output sections like the below answers do, it'll then send the progress bars to stdout instead of stderr. I haven't found a clean way of sending progress bar sections to stderr and regular log messages to stdout

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found something here: [[Console] A better progress bar #10356](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10356)

```php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

$output = new ConsoleOutput();

$bar1 = new ProgressBar($output, 10);
$bar2 = new ProgressBar($output, 20);
$bar2->setProgressCharacter('#');
$bar1->start();
print "\n";
$bar2->start();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    // up one line
    $output->write("\033[1A");
    usleep(100000);
    if ($i <= 10) {
        $bar1->advance();
    }
    print "\n";
    $bar2->advance();
}
```

Effect:

[image: ProgressBar]

You must move the console cursor to the appropriate line (up and down) before updating the bar. But it works. I confirm.

Answer (score 10):

With Symfony 4.1 this is supported without manual cursor-control, see
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html#console-multiple-progress-bars:

```
$section1 = $output->section();
$section2 = $output->section();

$progress1 = new ProgressBar($section1);
$progress2 = new ProgressBar($section2);

$progress1->start(100);
$progress2->start(100);

$i = 0;
while (++$i < 100) {
    $progress1->advance();

    if ($i % 2 === 0) {
         $progress2->advance(4);
    }

    usleep(50000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.6 / linux

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

$output = new ConsoleOutput();

$bar1 = new ProgressBar($output->section(), 10);
$bar2 = new ProgressBar($output->section(), 20);
$bar2->setProgressCharacter('#');
$bar1->start();
print "\n";
$bar2->start();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    // up one line
    $output->write("\033[1A");
    usleep(100000);
    if ($i <= 10) {
        $bar1->advance();
    }
    print "\n";
    $bar2->advance();
}
```

Answer (score -4):

In Laravel, you can do this to create multiple progress bars.

```
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;


    $output = new ConsoleOutput();
    
    $totalUsers->chunk(100, function($users) use($output) {
        $bar = new ProgressBar($output, count($users));
        $bar->start();

        $users->each(function($user) use($bar) {
            $this->performTask($user);
            $bar->advance();
        });

        $bar->finish();
        print "\n";
    });
```